# How to remove the Poly line from the Google Map v2 android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, polyline

I am successfully making and drawing poly lines on a marker click event. But there is a thing happening which I do not want to be happen.

And that is when I click on marker Let say JackiMarker it draws route to the target location but then I click to second marker let say MichaelMarker it also draws the route but the previous marker is still there which I do not want to be.

I am sing [this](https://github.com/zaffar-saffee/Android/blob/master/routes%20googleMaps%20v2/Route.java) code to draw and remove the marker. It has the clearRoute function but it is not working for me , please help me what to do . Please help me in removing the last polyline I have drawn on map.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this,

```
Polyline polyline = this.mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().....);
```

Then when you want to remove it:

```
polyline.remove();
```

If you have lots of `Polylines`, just add them to a List as they are put on the map:

```
List<Polyline> polylines = new ArrayList<Polyline>();

for(....)
{
  polylines.add(this.mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()....));

}
```

And when you want to delete:

```
for(Polyline line : polylines)
{
line.remove();
}
polylines.clear();
```

The key is to keep a reference to the `Polyline objects` and call `.remove()` on each one.

Comment: Try this 
for(Polyline line : polylines)
{ 
   if (isSpecificPolyline(line))

       line.remove();
}

Answer (score 0):

It is 100 % working code which I shared in the question , the problem was in my end .
what I was doing , was trying to delete the path when clicked on the marker and on the OnMarkerClickListener I was initiating the Route Class , which created another instance of the same class thus creating the array of polylines from 0 index which Is why i was not getting into the for loop of the clearRoute method.

so by instantiating the Route class as a global solved my problem.